# how to save old value to a PUT when I PUT a single value ReactJS/NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I would like to explain my problem of the day.

I map a database, then I display the result in a card

I get several results

So problem and the next one, when I modify a result, it empties all my other values, while I would like to keep the other values ​​of the other fields.

How can I fix this issue?thx all

make room for the code :)

```
class Chat extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
    data: [],
};
}
   onChangegame(e) {
    this.setState({ game: e.target.value })
}

onChangename(e) {
    this.setState({ name: e.target.value })
}

putname = (e, chat) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const config = {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ id: chat.id, name: this.state.name, game: this.state.game, }),
    };
    const url = "http://localhost:4242/api/putname";
    fetch(url, config)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            if (res.error) {
                alert(res.error);
            } else {
                alert(`ajouté avec l'ID ${res}!`);
            }
        }).catch(e => {
            console.error(e);
        }).finally(() => this.setState({ redirect: true }));
}

    render() {
    let datas = this.state.data.map(chat => {
        return (
    
       <div key={chat.id}>
       <form onSubmit={(e) => this.putname(e, chat)}>
       <p> {chat.name} </p>
       <input type="text"
       id="name"
       onChange={this.handleChange}
       value={this.state.name}
       name="name"
       />
       <input type="submit" value="modifier" />
       </form>
       <form onSubmit={(e) => this.putname(e, chat)}>
       <p> {chat.game} </p>
       <input type="text"
       id="game"
       onChange={this.handleChange}
       value={this.state.game}
       name="game"
       />
       <input type="submit" value="modifier" />
       </form>
       </div>
       return (
        <div>
            {datas}
        </div>
          )
         }
        }

    export default Chat
```

My Back

```
 putname = (e, chat) => {
e.preventDefault();
const config = {
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ id: chat.id, name: this.state.name, game: this.state.game }),
};
const url = "http://localhost:4242/api/putname";
fetch(url, config)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        if (res.error) {
            alert(res.error);
        } else {
            alert(`ajouté avec l'ID ${res}!`);
        }
    }).catch(e => {
        console.error(e);
    }).finally(() => this.setState({ redirect: true }));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem that I see is when you update the state you aren't preserving the previous values. For example:

instead of:

```js
onChangegame(e) {
    this.setState({ game: e.target.value })
}

onChangename(e) {
    this.setState({ name: e.target.value })
}
```

, use:

```js
onChangegame(e) {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, game: e.target.value })
}

onChangename(e) {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, name: e.target.value })
}
```

or even a better way it's using the same handler by destructing `e.target` object:

```js
onChange(e) {
    const { value, name } = e.target
    this.setState({ ...this.state, [name]: [value] })
}

// ... and the in your inputs


    render() {
    let datas = this.state.data.map(chat => {
        return (
    
       <div key={chat.id}>
       <form onSubmit={(e) => this.putname(e, chat)}>
       <p> {chat.name} </p>
       <input type="text"
       id="name"
       onChange={this.onChange}
       value={this.state.name}
       name="name"
       />
       <input type="submit" value="modifier" />
       </form>
       <form onSubmit={(e) => this.putname(e, chat)}>
       <p> {chat.game} </p>
       <input type="text"
       id="game"
       onChange={this.onChange}
       value={this.state.game}
       name="game"
       />
       <input type="submit" value="modifier" />
       </form>
       </div>
       return (
        <div>
            {datas}
        </div>
          )
```